# Testing PHP Web Service locally by using android app

Tags: php, android, web-services, testing

I am new to web services and planning to design a php webservice for my android app on my local machine which will send some user informations to database and generate some JSON data. But the problem is i am little confused about how to test it.

For example lets say that my webservice will locate on my local machine like below `http://localhost:80/webservice/register.php`

And my ip address is 192.168.1.X
Than is it possible for my android app to use this web service by using this url `http://192.168.1.X:80/webservice/register.php`

Normally since webservices are on the internet any program can access them. But i thought that i can test my webservice with my android app since both my pc and android device are on the same subnet. 
If someone make things clear and tell me a way for testing a web service locally i appreciated

Comment: you are confused in which thing??You are doing it correctly

Comment: I think so..But i just want to make sure since i havent tried it before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to call the web service in the local network also from the android app. But Your device and Your server on which Web Service running must have on the same network and Your firewall or any proxy server must be off on the server.